# How to search a range of number in splunk

Tags: splunk

In splunk, how can I search for a rang of number (e.g. from "Test213" to "Test220")?

I tried 'test2[13-20]" or 'test2(13-20)" but it does not work?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you searching for through raw data for the characters 'Test213', or is that the value of a field?

I ask because if it's a value it's quite easy, you just add a couple filters:

```
| where myField>212 
| where myfield<221
```

If it's just raw data, my suggestion would be to make a field, and then extract the integer, kinda like this:

something like:

```
| rex "Test(?<myfield>\d+)" 
| where myField>212 
| where myfield<221
```